# Python file names as dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary, key, filenames

I would like to create a dictionary "file_stats" containing objects with file statistics while parsing a drive or folder. 
I use the path+filename combination as keys for this dictionary
The objects have a method called "addScore".
My problem is that file names sometimes contain characters like "-" that lead to these errors:

```
Error: Yara Rule Check error while checking FILE: C:\file\file-name Traceback (most recent call last):
File "scan.py", line 327, in process_file
addScore(filePath)
File "scan.py", line 393, in addScore
file_stats[filePath].addScore(score)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'addScore'
```

I used the file names as keys for my dictionary to get a fast way of checking if the file is already in the dictionary.

Should I dismiss the idea of using the file path as dictionary keys or is there a easy way to escape the strings?

```
file_stats = {}
for root, directories, files in os.walk (drive, onerror=walkError, followlinks=False):
    filePath = os.path.join(root,filename)
    if not filePath in file_stats:
        file_stats[filePath] = FileStats()
        file_stats[filePath].addScore(score)
```

Comment: thank you for posting the error, but it would be nice if you accompanied it with your full code

Comment: A string is a legitimate dictionary key whether it contains dashes or not. The problem is probably elsewhere. The value of your dictionary looks like an integer.

Comment: The problem appears to be that you're storing an `int` object for the keyed filename, and not an instance of whatever `Class` you have written that has the `addScore` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here, the issue is like @pztrick pointed out in the comments to you question.

```
>>> class StatsObject(object):
...     def addScore(self, score):
...         print score
...
>>> file_stats = {"/path/to-something/hyphenated": StatsObject()}
>>> file_stats["/path/to-something/hyphenated"].addScore(10)
>>> file_stats["/another/hyphenated-path"] = 10
10
>>> file_stats["/another/hyphenated-path"].addScore(10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'addScore'
```

Does this minimal example work for you (with a different starting path presumably)

```
import os

class FileStats(object):
    def addScore(self, score):
        print score

score = 10
file_stats = {}
for root, directories, files in os.walk ("/tmp", followlinks=False):
    for filename in files:
        filePath = os.path.join(root,filename)
        if not filePath in file_stats:
            file_stats[filePath] = FileStats()
            file_stats[filePath].addScore(score)
```

Comment: Ah - damn. I missed a ".addScore" function in a part of the code and removed the code line setting the score directly as I used it in a previous version. Your hints were right. Thank you.